# Why does Area produce finite values for this area?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Let us consider in 13.3.1 on Windows 10 the region

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{x*y >= 8, y >= 8 x^3, y <= 27}, {x, y}];
```

and its area

```
Area[reg]
```

> `179/8 - 8 Log[27/8]`

```
N[%]
```

> `12.6438`

as well as

```
Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] reg]
```

and

```
Area[DiscretizeRegion[reg, AccuracyGoal -> 5, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]]
```

and

```
Area[DiscretizeRegion[reg, AccuracyGoal -> 5, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .01}]]
```

Both commands produce `70.248`.

As @Domen noticed, the region is unbounded as

```
RegionPlot[x*y >= 8 &&y >= 8 x^3 &&y <= 27,{x, -30, 10},{y, -30, 30},PlotPoints->50]
```

[image]

shows and its area is infinite.

Edit. The substantial edit (infinite area instead of two finite different values of the area ) has been made due to the valuable Domen's comment. Many thanks from me to him for it. Domen is a real coauthor of the edited question.

Comment: You don't specify the boundaries correctly, namely, look at for example `RegionPlot[x*y >= 8 && y >= 8 x^3 && y <= 27, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 50},  PlotPoints -> 50]`. Then, `Area[ImplicitRegion[{x*y >= 8, y >= 8 x^3, y <= 27, x > 0}, {x, y}]]` gives the correct result.

Comment: @Domen: Thank you for your valuable comment. Indeed, `Area[ImplicitRegion[{x*y >= 8, y >= 8 x^3, y <= 27, x >= 0, 
   y >= 0}, {x, y}]]` performs `195/8 - 8 Log[27/8]`. However, the problem remains: `reg` is unbounded, so `Area[reg]` should return the input or `Infinity`  or, at least, a warning.

Comment: `Area[ImplicitRegion[{x >= 1 && y <= 5 && y <= x^2 || x < -1, 
   y <= x^2}, {x, y}]]` results in `Infinity`.

Comment: As well as `Area[ImplicitRegion[{x >= 1 && y <= 5 && y >= x^2 || x < -1, y <= x^2,
    y <= 5}, {x, y}]]`.

Comment: The question is closed due to "This question arises due to a simple mistake such as a trivial syntax error, incorrect capitalization, spelling mistake, or other typographical error and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation. Closed 9 hours ago." Sorry,  I don't find nothing of the above in the question which obtained two pluses.

Comment: It was a simple mistake because you did not make correct specification of your region. If you have other question or troubles which emerged in the comments above (such as `Area` giving wrong result for unbounded regions), please edit the question accordingly to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: @Domen: Thank you. I followed your advice.

Comment: This appears to be a bug, at least on MM 13.1 on a Mac.  In particular, `reg2 = ImplicitRegion[{x*y >= 8, y >= 8 x^3, y <= 5}, {x, y}]; Area[reg2]` yields `-2` for some reason.

Comment: @user64494: On version `13.0.1` `Area@ImplicitRegion[{x*y >= 8, y >= 8 x^3, y <= 27}, {x, y}]` outputs  correctly `Infinity`.